# async TypeError: cb is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I've created the following method to aid me in finding an item and updating another object attribute with certain value like this:

```
  mergeAinBbyAttr: function(a, b, attr, val, cb) {
    async.forEach(a, function(itemA, cb) {
        async.forEach(b, function(itemB, cb) {
            if (itemA[attr] == itemB[attr]) {
              itemB[val] = itemA[val];
            }
            cb(null, itemB);
          },
          function(e, result) {
            cb(e, result);
          });
      },
      function(e, result) {
        cb(e, result);
      });
  }
```

The problem is that I get:

> TypeError: cb is not a function

in the last `cb(e, result);`. I have to admit I am a bit brain dead an the answer must be dead simple.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no guarantee that `cb` will be a function. Someone can pass whatever they want or pass nothing at all (in which case `cb` will be `undefined`).

If you believe that you are code that invokes this function is such that `cb` is guaranteed to be a function, then maybe add an `assert(typeof cb === 'function');` at the start of `mergeAinBbyAttr`. (You may need to add a `const assert = require('assert');` at the top of your file.)

If this is library code that someone else can call or if you are otherwise not guaranteed to receive a function for `cb`, add some type checking:

```
if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
  // Do something here: Throw an error, set `cb` to a no-op function, whatever
}
```

Comment: I see what happened, I was calling it with .exec instead of function() (ie callback)...thanks your answer took me the right way!